# Node.js mssql package select query cache problem

Tags: node.js, sql-server, pm2

I try to retrieve data from SQL Server using npm `mssql` package. When I used postman to make a request, I got same data (resultset) at every time although data was changed.

My SQL Server connection config and code is here:

```
   const sql = require('mssql');
     const config = {
     user: 'XXXX',
     password: 'XXXX',
     server: 'XXXX',
     database: 'XXXX',
     pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 10
      },
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
}

 const getConnection = async () => {
            try {
                const conn = await sql.connect(config);
                return {pool: conn, err: false, errorMSG: null};
            } catch (err) {
                return {conn: null, err: true, errorMSG: err}
            }
        };
```

And my db function :

```
 const conn = await getConnection();

    if (conn.err == false) {
        try {
            let result = await conn.pool.request()
                .input('registryNumber', sql.NVarChar(50), registryNumber)
                .input('password', sql.NVarChar(50), password)
                .query('SELECT role FROM [OperatorLogin].[dbo].[TBL_users]' +
                    'WHERE [TBL_users].[registryNumber] = @registryNumber AND [TBL_users].[password] = @password AND [TBL_users].[isActive] = 1 ')
            if (result.rowsAffected[0] >= 1) {
                return { Execution: true, ExecutionCode: 1, ExecutionMessage: "Record is available", ExecutionData: result.recordset }
            }
            else {
                return { Execution: true, ExecutionCode: 2, ExecutionMessage: "No records", ExecutionData: "" }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            return { Execution: false, ExecutionCode: -1, ExecutionMessage: "DB pool request error : " + err, ExecutionData: "" }
        }
    }
    else {
        return { Execution: false, ExecutionCode: -1, ExecutionMessage: " DB error : " + conn.errorMSG, ExecutionData: "" }
    }
```

On the other hand, I use pm2 and reverse proxy on Windows server.

What may be problem ? What am I missing ?

Comment: `I got same data ( resultset ) at everytime although data was changed...`  What exactly do you mean by this?  If you get the same data / resultset, what was changed in that?  Is it just that the data comes back in a different order?

Comment: Aside... are you really storing plaintext passwords in a database in this day and age?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you for your feedback. This is not a production code. This is only node.js learning attempt. On the other hand, I'm trying to get help and fix the problem, so I think the "Password" storage technique shouldn't be the problem now. If you have any helpful ideas, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @squillman I mean that although the data in the database has changed, the same data is returned in the postman request. For example, Role was changed by admin panel from "Admin" to "User", but Select query is still retrieving role as Admin for a while. I also point out that I did not create any cache mechanism. What may be reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found the problem, the correctly syntax to use a pool connection:

```js
  sql.connect(sqlConfig).then((pool) =>
    pool.query(query)
      .then(res => result = res.recordset)
      .then(pool.close)
  )
```

Or with Async/Await

```js
  try {
    let connection = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)

    let result = await sql.query(query)

    await connection.close()

    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
```

It's not a cache problem, just need to close the connection after run a query.