# React + Next.js + Typescript + Chakra UI SSR problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm developing an app with this stack on the title, my app works fine but when i try to disable javascript on the browser to see Next.js SSR works, the app still being rendering but the components of chakra like tabs and accordion and some styles stop to work. Anyone using this stack seeing this before?

I already trying to search for a similar problem but i find nothing like this.

Comment: Ok, i found the problem in my backend! https://stackoverflow.com/a/76310326/20120891